# dominant of a polyhedron

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, optimization, discrete-optimization, discrete-geometry

On page 8 of this pdf ([https://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~vjost/mpri/prelimILP.pdf](https://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/%7Evjost/mpri/prelimILP.pdf)) from Schrijvers book "combinatorial optimization" the dominant of a polytope is defined as:

P$^\uparrow$ := {$y \in \mathbb{R}^n | \exists x \in P : y \geq x$ } = P + $\mathbb{R}^n_+$

P$^\downarrow$ := {$y \in \mathbb{R}^n | \exists x \in P : y \leq x$ } = P - $\mathbb{R}^n_+$

for P $\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$

how can $y$ be greater or less than $x$ when both are in $\mathbb{R}^n$. how can they be compared?

And what do P + $\mathbb{R}^n_+$  and P - $\mathbb{R}^n_+$ mean?

Comment: When dealing with polytopes, we generally define inequality between vectors as inequality satisfied for all dimensions. In schrijver, this is defined section 2.4.

Comment: Your problem more seems to be about reading the set notation as such: the first $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ in fact just says: take _those_ $y$s from that realm, _which fulfill_ the requirements after the pipe symbol. (Not all of them!)